# Trying to toggle a class but I get error 'toggle' of undefined using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get my class to toggle but it won't work. I get an error message saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined".

This is my Javascript:

```
var sound = document.getElementById("sound");
var two = document.getElementsByClassName("two");
var twoanimated = document.getElementsByClassName("twoanimated");

function animatie () {
    two.classList.toggle("twoanimated");
}

sound.addEventListener("click", animatie);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show all relevant code, HTML and CSS too.

Comment: @AndrewLi That might explain why, but this is not a duplicate.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Why not? Looks like a duplicate to me.

Comment: @AndrewLi Tell me if I should hammer now. If you feel so, I'll do it.

Comment: @AndrewLi I'll do now.

Comment: @AndrewLi Done... `:)`

Comment: Duplicate or not, it was exacly what I needed to know, so thank for the quick reply. Sorry if Im stupid for asking a question that has already been asked, I did look for it but couldn't find it.

Comment: @H0ndman2 You want me to undelete my answer so you can copy it, and let me know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is here:

```
var two = document.getElementsByClassName("two");
```

The `two` is a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) and not a single element. So you need to do:

```
two[0].classList.toggle("twoanimated");
```

The above code works if there's only one single element for the class name `twoanimated`. If there are multiple, please use a counter loop something like this:

```
function animatie () {
  for (var i = 0; i < two.length; i++) {
    two[i].classList.toggle("twoanimated");
  }
}
```